# How come my accuracy is so oscillatory?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, linear, keras

I'm training up a linear regression model on some vehicle data (sorry I can't be more specific than that). I'm experiencing some very strange output on the accuracy of the model and I'm not sure it's a good thing or bad.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
normalizer = Normalization(input_shape=[train_x.shape[1],], axis=None)
normalizer.adapt(train_x.axes[0])

linear_model = Sequential([
    normalizer,
    Dense(units=1)
])

linear_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss='mean_absolute_error',
    metrics=['acc'])

history = linear_model.fit(
    train_x,
    train_y,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=128,
    verbose=0,
    validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

Where:

```
linear_model.summary()
```

Produces:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
normalization_3 (Normalizati (None, 19)                3         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 20        
=================================================================
Total params: 23
Trainable params: 20
Non-trainable params: 3
_________________________________________________________________
```

The graph below shows what I'm seeing. I'm used to seeing the accuracy start off at around 50% and then increase fairly smoothly before converging on a final accuracy. This accuracy is all over the place. Any help?

[image: Output from linear model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that your learning rate is too high.  The Adam optimizer can become unstable in areas where the gradient is very low.  In this case, you have a very small network and you may be close to an optimum in a very flat region of the gradient.

Try lowering the learning rate and see if the oscillation goes away, or try switching to a different optimizer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried that and the accuracy shoots to ~90% after just a few epochs. Should that be something to worry about?

Comment: It is only something to worry about of you validation accuracy drops at the same time.  If your valuation accuracy stays up, I would say you're in good shape.  If it drops, you're over training.

Comment: Here's another, better explanation of what I suspect is happening in your case.   https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/strange-behavior-with-adam-optimizer-when-training-for-too-long

Comment: By the way, if my answer worked for you, please "accept" my answer.  I could use the reputation point boost.  8^)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you could only select a correct answer after 2 days. My bad

Comment: Thanks!  I was probably just being impatient.  I appreciate the boost!  8^D